# How do I use try (or tryCatch) to fit either a 4 parameter logistic model or 3 parameter logistic model

Tags: r

I would like to fit a 4 parameter logistic regression model to some toxicity data using the package `drc`.  This is an example data set:

```
exp.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 14, ncol = 2))

exp.df[,1] <- c(3200, 9600, 25600, 25600, 25600, 1600, 800,
                6400, 19200, 0, 12800, 1200, 400, 2400)

exp.df[,2] <- c(0.5855615, 0.9625668, 0.4064171, 0.4973262,
                0.4732620, 1.0000000, 0.6764706, 0.4652406,
                0.5106952, 0.7566845, 0.5427807, 0.5106952, 
                0.5935829, 0.4759358)

names(exp.df) <- c("Dose", "Response")

Dose_Response <- drm(Response ~ Dose, data = exp.df,
                     fct = LL.4(), type = "binomial")
```

results in this warning:

> Error in optim(startVec, opfct, hessian = TRUE, method = optMethod,
>   control = list(maxit = maxIt,  :    non-finite finite-difference value
>   [4] Error in drmOpt(opfct, opdfct1, startVecSc, optMethod,
>   constrained, warnVal,  :    Convergence failed

If I run a 3 parameter logistic regresison, it works.

```
Dose_Response <- drm(Response ~ Dose, data = exp.df,
                     fct = LL.3(), type = "binomial")
```

Can I use try or `tryCatch` to test the 4 parameter logistic first, then the 3 parameter logistic regression?  Or is there another solution?

Comment: I don't know R but it looks like you only have 2 cols, i.e. 2 features. You should run a 3 parameter model in this case. You can't try the 4 parameters if you don't have 3 features + a bias term. So the 3 will always work and the 4 will never work. That is, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `cluster(id)` term? After I added a sham one in, your data solved with both `LL.3()` and `LL.4()`.